# Is it necessary to drop temporary tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem dropping a *temporary* table. The user account does not have the 'drop' privilege. I don't want to grant that privilege due to security reasons.

I tried to find a privilege like 'drop temporary' but there isn't. It seems the only option is to remove all the 'drop table' statements. I know that the temporary tables will be automatically dropped after the DB sessions end.

However, I'm not sure if there are any side effects leaving this job to MySQL. Please, advice.

Comment: As mentioned here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables _To keep privileges for temporary and nontemporary tables separate, a common workaround for this situation is to create a database dedicated to the use of temporary tables. Then for that database, a user can be granted the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege, along with any other privileges required for temporary table operations done by that user._

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Temporary tables are dropped automatically as soon as you disconnect from database

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

So - create them, use and don't bother of theirs deletion

Comment: If you use a connection pool (hikari, c3p0, etc), then your connections will probably be open for longer than you'd expect, so be careful. It may make sense to manually drop temporary tables in that case.

Comment: @Alden it makes sense to configure software properly so that everything worked as expected. Connection poolers must reset the connection on client disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

It will use current machine's Ram space.
So better idea is drop the temporary table on the next step ,once its use is over

Answer (score 0):

If the user has CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege, he can perform DROP TABLE, INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT.

Please see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables